# How can I use four finger drag and switch between workspaces with my touchpad on Ubuntu?

Tags: touchpad, gestures

Is there any way to make Ubuntu 16.04 know when i drag with 4 fingers on my touchpad or other gestures and do specific actions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with [Touchégg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg).

This is an open source script you install onto your machine via the command line. There is an alternative GUI but I have not used that.

Once installed you can execute `touchegg` from the command line and it will tell you which touch devices you have.

After this you can edit the configuration file, mentioned in the instructions, to tell Touchégg what to do with 4 finger actions (among others).